# Laravel: include some js only when using some Blade layout views but not others

Tags: laravel, include, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

In a Laravel environment, I have a `js.blade.php` (to be included in all my layout views), holding global javascript files and some `@yield` placeholders, like this

```
<!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ie10-viewport/1.0.0/ie10-viewport.min.js"></script>
<!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
@yield('js-plugins')
<!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
<!-- BEGIN SOME OTHER GENERAL PLUGINS -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/dummy1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/dummy2.min.js"></script>
<!-- END SOME OTHER GENERAL PLUGINS -->
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
@yield('js-scripts')
<!-- END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
<!-- BEGIN SCRIPTS TO BE RENDERED ONLY IN SOME LAYOUT VIEWS -->
...
<!-- END SCRIPTS TO BE RENDERED ONLY IN SOME LAYOUT VIEWS -->
<!-- BEGIN MY CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
<script src="{{ asset('backend/scripts.js') }}"></script>
<!-- END MY CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
```

Do you see the `<!-- BEGIN SCRIPTS TO BE RENDERED ONLY IN SOME LAYOUT VIEWS -->` part? Here I should have scripts that goes in `master.blade.php` layout view (used for most pages when user is logged in) but not in, i.e., `unlogged.blade.php` layout view (used for login, or retrieve lost password, or everything else that involves a non-logged user): I mean, i.e., scripts belonging to sidebar nav (that of course is in 'internal' pages but not in 'external' ones)

Well, how can I tell Laravel "when using `master.blade.php` view put some scripts in that `...` part, otherwise leave it as-is"? The goal is to leverage only the `js.blade.php` view to keep things DRY

I took a lok at `@push` and `@stacks`, but they are not clear to me and I don't know if I can use them somehow

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try to add file.js like source in the <script> tags? I use it like this.

Comment: I will use `ViewComposer` and `if` statement in this case.

Comment: @JaredChu, please can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Use **`if`** statement and **`@include`** instead of `@yield` in this case:

**`js.blade.php`:**

```
<!-- BEGIN SCRIPTS TO BE RENDERED ONLY IN SOME LAYOUT VIEWS -->
@if(!isset($limit) || (isset($limit) && !$limit))
    <script src="{{asset('js/home.js')}}"></script>
@endif
<!-- END SCRIPTS TO BE RENDERED ONLY IN SOME LAYOUT VIEWS -->
```

**`master.blade.php`**

```
@include('js')
```

**`unlogged.blade.php` (you do not want to render some script here)**

```
@include('js',['limit'=>true])
```

Full example: https://github.com/jaredchu/laravel-dynamic-view-example/tree/master/resources/views